# Where does nodejs get msg value in net example?

Tags: node.js

In the nodejs documentation for net, they provide the following example:

```
var net = require('net');

function socket(msg) {
    console.log('Server connected.');
    msg.on('end', function() {
        console.log('Server disconnected.');
    });
    msg.write('Hello\n');
    msg.pipe(msg);
}

var net = net.createServer(socket);

net.listen(1337,function() {
    console.log('Server bound to 1337.');
});
```

When createServer is passed "socket" function, where does the "msg" come from in "function socket(msg)"?

Comment: The code that eventually calls the function `socket` passes an argument to it. Not sure what exactly you want to know. At some point, the callback will be called as `func(someArg)` and that's it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`msg` is a Duplex stream that is created internally by node's built-in 'net' module that represents the readable and writable portions of the connection.

When a new connection is made to the server, it creates this object and passes it to the connection handler/callback.